# Hibernate Jndi Tomcat Error : Not supported by BasicDataSource

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat, jndi

im actually trying to set up a hibernate and jdbc connection pooling by JNDI, but i fail to success to do so. After hours of research, i come to you, maybe someone does know the answer.

First things first: I`m using Tomcat 8.0 and Hibernate 5.2.8. I cant actually alternate in those, if thats required to make it work.

The error im getting is : "java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported by BasicDataSource"

What i found out so far : The error seem to occur (im not 100% sure) due to a change in the DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection, where "getConnection(Username, Password" is 'depricated' (Actually, it simply throws this error).

But here`s the catch, even if i dont transfer any parameters, i get this exception. I tried to make my very own Interface of "javax.sql.DataSource" to overcome this, but that didnt help either.

Another thing : JDBC works just fine, the only problem is hibernate.

Following up the context, web and class infos :

Context :

```
<Resource name="jdbc/basic"
        global="jdbc/basic"
        auth="Container" 
        type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
        maxActive="10"
        maxIdle="20"
        maxWait="10000"
        username="root"
        password="1" 
        driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        testOnBorrow="true"
        url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/javatest"
    />
```

Web :

```
  <resource-ref>
      <description>JNDI MYSql JDBC Connection</description>
      <res-ref-name>jdbc/basic</res-ref-name>
      <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
      <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
  </resource-ref>
```

Code :

```
public TestClass() {
    try {
         Connection jdbc = ((javax.sql.DataSource) new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/basic")).getConnection();
         System.out.println(new Configuration().configure("managedbeans/hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory().openSession().createQuery("Select * from Testdata").list().size());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

if anymore information is required, im happy to provide

Edith:

As Requested :

```
<hibernate-configuration> 
    <session-factory>

        <property name="hibernate.connection.datasource">java:comp/env/jdbc/basic</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property> 
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property> 
        <property name="hibernate.max_fetch_depth">3</property>

        <!-- Mapped annotated entity-->
        <mapping class="managedbean.TestPojo"/>

    </session-factory> 
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: Can you print your hibernate.cfg.xml as well?

Comment: I added the cfg.xml.

Comment: I noticed you mention `managedBean` for your mappings but then you mention `managedBeans` when you configured Hibernate.  Do you have both paths, is that a typo, or the reason for the failure.  I stood up a Tomcat8 instance with Hibernate 5.2.8, no JNDI issues.

Comment: I just upgraded to tomcat 8.5, as recomended by someone from Hibernate, which did the trick. That managedbean/beans error was due to handwritten code, the hibernate config was not copied from the orginal project as i had it not at hand at that moment. Nevertheless, Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly it is the same as mentioned here: [tomcat-connection-pooling-java-lang-unsupportedoperationexception-not-support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27792692/tomcat-connection-pooling-java-lang-unsupportedoperationexception-not-support)

Summary of one of the answers:
If hibernate does find the properties `hibernate.connection.username` or/and `hibernate.connection.password` within the classpath it uses the deprecated `getConnection(user,password)` method.

Comment: Firstoff, thank you for your comment. Yes, that made me think i might have the same issue, But as i mentioned, i tried any method to remove Username and Password. Even not even putting it neither config and hbm.xml works. Also the "own interface" method didnt want to work